# Decoding utf8 string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8

Im trying to display a string with emojis on a text widget. The string is encoded using utf8. My question is how can I decode the whole string so it will display to the text properly?

here is the string with emojis:

Testing emoticons post `\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\udc4c\ud83e\udd70\ud83d\ude02\ud83e\udd73\u2708\ufe0f\ud83d\udc4a\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude01\ud83e\udd23\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude01\u2708\ufe0f\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude4f\ud83e\udd22\ud83d\ude2d`

Currently I have this function :

```
String utf8convert(String text) {
   List<int> bytes = text.toString().codeUnits;
   return utf8.decode(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Is it not working if you use utf8.decode directly to text?

Comment: @hoangquyy it's not working.

Comment: @hoangquyy if I copy the text and paste it directly to a text widget it is working, but if its coming from the api the emoticons are not decoded.

Comment: This is how I decode utf8: var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)) with convert is import 'dart:convert' as convert;

Comment: thanks I will try your suggestion @hoangquyy

Comment: @hoangquyy I tried  final parsedJson = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)); but still no luck :(

Comment: Can you give me your api so I can try?

Comment: What is the result if you print the string of emoji from api to console?

Comment: @hoangquyy it will display same string I posted above.

Comment: And you take that string put to Text but it still not display like you want? it's weird

Comment: @hoangquyy yes, but If I copy and paste it to text, it will work.

Comment: I think you get wrong string

Comment: @hoangquyy no because when I print the text from the api, I will get the same string I posted above. Do you think I need to use font that support emojis?

Comment: Just try, it's easy to implement. In my case, some font not support my language, so maybe emojis too

Comment: I tried using emoji one font, but still no luck.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using API to get data with emojis.

```
final response =
      await _httpClient.get(uri);
jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Text widget directly works fine 
code snippet
 `Text('\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\udc4c\ud83e\udd70\ud83d\ude02\ud83e\udd73\u2708\ufe0f\ud83d\udc4a\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude01\ud83e\udd23\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude01\u2708\ufe0f\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude4f\ud83e\udd22\ud83d\ude2d'),`

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;


  void _incrementCounter() {


    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\udc4c\ud83e\udd70\ud83d\ude02\ud83e\udd73\u2708\ufe0f\ud83d\udc4a\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude01\ud83e\udd23\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude01\u2708\ufe0f\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude4f\ud83e\udd22\ud83d\ude2d'),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it works if you paste it directly on a Text widget, but if its comming from the api like I posted above, the emojis are not working.

Comment: any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonDecode from dart:convert. For example if you receive text data from Api, you can receive data that contains special format string like '\udc4a\ud83d\ude01...' for emoji or accentual characters. JsonDecode will help to show string properly.

```
 final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('apiaddress'), body: _body);
  var decode = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
  print(decode);
```