# Decoding emojis in a network request

Tags: flutter, dart, emoji

I am sending some emojis to a remote API with the following format:

`☺☺`

When I receive the same data, I receive it malformed:

`ðâºðâºð¤ð¤ð¤`

I'm using the standard [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) client to perform the network requests.

What should I do in order to decode correctly the emojis?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425849/decoding-utf8-string-in-flutter/69394052#69394052

Answer (score 0):

it could be from the backend if he is save these emojis in the wrong encoding

Answer (score 0):

An UTF8 conversion was needed:

`import 'dart:convert' show utf8;`

`utf8.decode(receivedString.runes.toList())`